# Using a Login Page

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

how do i fix the issue

Did not login just throw exception (index -1 requested with a size 0)

```
String sql="select * from beta where uname='"+unam+"' and pwd='"+pwd+"'";
cur=db.rawQuery(sql,null);
if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
    String nm = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("uname"));
    String pd = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("pwd"));
    if ((nm.equals(unam)) && (pd.equals(pwd))) {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login NOT Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how your code could be throwing this exception.  Does the `beta` table really have a `uname` and `pwd` column?

Comment: what are you finding in **debugging**?

Comment: Did you check data is empty or not before you retrieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your code to this:

```
String sql="select * from beta where uname='"+unam+"' and pwd='"+pwd+"'";
cur=db.rawQuery(sql,null);
if(cur != null && cur.getCount() > 0 && cur.moveToFirst()) {
    String nm = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("uname"));
    String pd = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("pwd"));
    if ((nm.equals(unam)) && (pd.equals(pwd))) {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login NOT Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to get the record from the database of the input username and password. So if you get that record mean that logged in successful.

No need to get the username and password from cursor. You just need to check the size of cursor if you get one record than you can say that user is logged in.

I assume that username is unique in database.

```
String sql="select * from beta where uname='"+unam+"' and pwd='"+pwd+"'";
cur=db.rawQuery(sql,null);
if(cur != null && cur.getCount() > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login NOT Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```